# Azure DevOpsにおけるusersの表示について

Tags: azure

プロジェクトへ外部ユーザーの招待(Invite)は成功しました。
外部ユーザーをstakeholderに割り当て後、[Organaization settings]-[users]を表示すると
プロジェクト関係者以外の全てのユーザーが表示されて困っています。
[Projects]は招待したプロジェクト以外表示されていないため、[users]も関係するプロジェクトのユーザー、または[Organaization settings]を非表示とするような方法は可能でしょうか？

Answer (score 2):

残念ながらそれはできないはずです。Organizationはセキュリティ最大の枠になるので、どうしてもほかのユーザー(特にAzure ADのguest)を参照させたくない場合はorganizationを分割することになります。

現在はOrganizationを分割してもサブスクリプションが同一であれば、費用は一つにまとめられるので、ユーザーでセキュリティの範囲を考えるといいかと思います。